# EPS images blurry in ID

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, import

I bought 20 EPS line art images from Shutterstock to use in a book. But, all the images are pixelated. I got in touch with Shutterstock and they told me that the images are fine and the problem is on my side.

I also saved the image as AI, PDF, and TIFF, but nothing has changed. I have the View on Display, High Performance and still nothing. I uninstalled the program and reinstalled and still nothing. My project is stalling because of that. Can please anybody help me out? I'm adding one of the images in the Preview program on the Mac and it looks perfect; it's only when it is in ID that looks jagged.

Many, many thanks!!

Preview of one of the EPS images. It looks perfect. Not like this in ID. Here you can see how it looks. I used Blending Mode, Multiply, but even without it, it is still blurry.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Links are identical. Show us what it looks like in INDD.

Comment: The one that you see in what it looks like in ID. I meant to add the Preview in Mac, but it didn't load. Does this help?

Comment: Lucian, any idea why the images are not behaving in ID?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the posted image. Is it a vector image? Does it look pixelated when you zoom in?

Comment: Maybe you just don't like the way InDesign renders vector? It might just *look* smoother in Mac's Preview. Try exporting a PDF from InDesign with the placed EPS and open it in Mac's Preview to see if that is the case.

Comment: You're probably not used to looking at linked EPS files in ID. The EPS you posted was fine and there's only one way ID will render EPS files. Display quality may be affected by your screen, but we can't know that, otherwise the screenshot looks pretty normal. Again, make sure sure you have High Quality Display turned on.

Comment: The same EPS file linked in my ID looked sharper by the way, so most likely something wrong with the way your screen works. Try looking at another screen, like save a PDF and look at it on your mobile.

Comment: It looks good on my phone. It's the first time I've used EPS images and am having a hard time figuring out whether there's something wrong with them because they simply don't look sharp on my screen, not even as PDF. Other formats are fine. But, if I change their formats, it's still the same. I'll run a proof at the local printer and see what happens. Thank you to everybody!!

Comment: I opened a PDF in Preview and it looks sharp when I zoom in, but at the size that I need it, rather small, in a poetry book, it still looks jugged. Should I try to replaced them with another picture, maybe bought elsewhere?

Comment: I can't be 100% sure without having the file, but if the image is vector it doesn't really matter how it's rendered on screen. Remember that your screen probably has a much lower resolution that the print. The contour will be as sharp as possible with a given printing device. The same with text. But of course both vector images and text can be reduced so much in size that it gets too small in print, but that's not really a technical problem, but a design problem.

Comment: Hello Wolff, I will have to run a proof to be sure that this is the case. From my screen, they look terrible, but everybody else-from other forums as well-tells me that they look good on their screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, check to see if you are in high-resolution viewing in InDesign or if it’s set as “typical”. Another option is to print it out from InDesign and check if it prints out clearly.

Answer (score 0):

EPS files are a hybrid format that includes Postscript vector instructions AND a bitmap preview image of the rendered vectors. That preview has a specific number of pixels and is not typically high-resolution. Programs such as InDesign can display the preview image, and depending on what that preview contains, and how large the image is sized in the layout program, the preview can be much worse than what will print IF the postscript vectors are what gets output for the printer.

You should not be concerned with the appearance of an EPS file in a layout program unless you suspect that there is not a clean, vector graphic within the EPS file. You could try to get more information from Shutterstock.

Converting the EPS file to another format is problematic because most formats do NOT preserve the vector graphics, they convert the vectors into a raster image at some (possibly controllable) resolution. Which might look bad if there are not enough pixels for the size at which the image will be printed.

Your "line art" images could be vectors, but then again, they may be raster (pixel) images that just happen to be stored in EPS format. Never a good idea, but it happens. You have to do some investigating to find out what your files are really made of, and if they will print at high enough resolution to avoid looking bad.